# How can you calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$ using the residue at $-i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Instead of using traditional upper-half semicircle, I have tried to calculate this integral using lower-half and have obtained $-\pi$, that is the opposite to the actual value.
Can anyone show me how to calculate it?

Comment: Can you show us how you calculated $-\pi$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you tried, but a common way in which you can get the result with the opposite sign is by taking the contour in the wrong direction since the residue theorem is written for positively oriented curves.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly Robert Lee is right about your error. The residue is the result of integrating around a closed curve in the *counter-clockwise* direction. If you traverse the curve in the clockwise direction, you get the opposite value.

If you use the upper half-circle and travel counter-clockwise, then the part of the curve on the real line is integrated from negative to positive, and taking the limit gives $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1}$. But if you use the lower half-circle, you can either go counter-clockwise, in which case the portion on the real line is integrated from positive to negative, so taking the limit gives $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1}$, or you can travel clockwise, in which case you do get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, but it is equal to the opposite of the residue, instead of the residue itself.

Either way, there is an additional negation you missed performing.